# How do I carry out further categorization in the following analysis?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, jupyter

The data used is Gapminder's data --> employment_above_15.csv

```
   # defining functions for finding correlation 
    def correlation(x,y):
        std_x = (x-x.mean())/(x.std(ddof = 0))
        std_y = (y-y.mean())/(y.std(ddof=0))
        return (std_x * std_y).mean()

    #function for calculating correlation for each country with time
    def emp_country(country,df):
        emp_country=df.loc[country]
        year_are=df.columns.values.astype(str).astype(int)
        return correlation(emp_country.values, year_are)`def 

    determing_cor_level(data):
        data1 = abs(data)
        if data1 < 0.4:
            return "Low"
        elif data1 < 0.7:
            return "Medium"
        else:
            return "High"

    def corr_type(data):
        if data > 0:
            return "(-)ve"
        elif data == 0:
            return "Null"
        else:
            return "(+)ve"

    def finding_corr(df):
        corr_list=[]
        corr_level=[]
        corr_types=[]
        for country in df.index.values.astype('str'):
            corr_value=emp_country(country,df)
            corr_list.append(corr_value)
            corr_level.append(determing_cor_level(corr_value))
            corr_types.append(corr_type(corr_value))
            df1= pd.DataFrame({'Correlation': corr_list,'Correlation Strength':corr_level, 'Correlation Type' : corr_types} ,
                  index= df.index.values.astype('str'))
        return df1

    finding_corr(employment_rate).head()
    finding_corr(employment_rate).groupby('Correlation Strength').count()['Correlation']
```

And I am getting the following output:
Correlation Strength
High      99
Low       29
Medium    50
Name: Correlation, dtype: int64

**But now I want to subcategorize and find as to how many of the countries having each type of Strength of Correlation,
 have (+)ve and (-)ve correlation.That is how many of the countries having High correlation have (+)ve correlation and how many have (-)ve correlation. How to do that?**

Answer (score 0):

finding_corr(employment_rate).groupby(['Correlation Strength','Country']).count()['Correlation']

--This might help

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on why this is a better function?